# How to consume and re-expose a Win32 type library using Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi, com, oxygene, typelib

I currently have a Win32 type library created in Delphi which I need to consume, implement and re-expose via .NET.  What are the steps necessary to bring the TLB into Prism so the interface can be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the .NET 2.0 sdk tool TLBIMP can create an assembly from a TLB file. Something like:

tlbimp.exe mytlb.tlb /out:MyTLB.Import.dll /namespace:MyTLBImport

Make sure you use /publickey /keyfile or /keycontainer if you want to sign it later on.

After the import, just reference the dll and use it as a regular library.